# How to override pixels drawn in a canvas of a previous paint?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm currently drawing this:

[image]

Is a red rectangle and on top is a blue rectangle with transparency. And I want to accomplish this (made in photoshop):

[image]

I've tried all posible BlendModes and PorterDuff modes (don't know the difference between the two but tried them all anyway) and I can't get my desired result, I've managed to cutout the part o the blue rectangle but it "cuts too deep" meaning that it puts a black rectangle instead of a white one.

Here is my code:

```
mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000"));
mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#330000FF"));

//mBackgroundPaint.setBlendMode(..BlendMode..); 
canvas.drawRoundRect(0, 0, size, size, rad, rad, mBackgroundPaint);
//mPaint.setBlendMode(..BlendMode..); 
canvas.drawRoundRect(0, 0, size/2, size, rad, rad, mPaint);
```

I need to use different Paints because this is an example but in reality the blue rectangle is an image with transparency.

Comment: What are you drawing this to, exactly? I mean, are you creating a `Bitmap` to be used later? Or are you drawing to a custom `View`'s `Canvas`, for instance?

Comment: I'm drawing directly into the view canvas

Comment: Well, to do it inline there, I'm pretty sure you've only got two options: `saveLayer()` and an `XferMode` on the blue paint, or clip the red draw. The first one is rather expensive, and the second is really only feasible if the clipped area is regular – e.g., rectangle, circle, or a combination thereof – but it doesn't sound like that's the case.

Comment: Saving the layer could work depending on the size though. What do you mean by clipping?

Comment: Clipping is marking out an area where subsequent draw operations will not draw, until the `Canvas` has been restored. For example, this would be pretty simple if the blue draw is always going to be a rounded rectangle, because you could just clip that area before drawing over the whole thing with red. Follow me?

Comment: The clipping sound like it could work I'm looking it on google but do you have a link?

Comment: Not really. I mean, they're standard `Canvas` methods, so you could have a look at the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#public-methods_1. I'm not sure that they have any examples of it, though.